# I have a ettus B200 mini. I want a function in C++ that shows if there is a hardware connection or not. Does this exist?

Tags: c++, usrp, uhd

I have a B200 mini. I would like a function in C++ that returns a flag regarding the hardware connection. So if there is a hardware connection, the function return 1. If there is not a connection, it returns 0. Does ettus have any functions like this?

Comment: What do you mean with hardware connection?

Comment: Like if the usb cable is connected

Comment: you can figure that out with the USB system you're using – i.e. using libusb

Comment: so, simply ask libusb if there is a USB device with the right VID/PID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using UHD, you can use the function [`uhd::device::find`](http://files.ettus.com/manual/classuhd_1_1device.html#a1b103f9db343b8ef9439677c670d05de). In any cases, it will return you an `std::vector<uhd::device_adrr_t>`. So if you give an hint to the `find` function, you can simply verify that your device is connected by checking the size of the vector returned. If you don't give any hint to the function, it will return all devices connected to the computer. You can then iterate and search for your specific device.